# laravel many to many delete and update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have many to many relationship .

in the blade code i sent many items with `actionID[]`

and then i insert them like this:

```
$detailsAttribute->actions()->sync(Input::get('action_id'));
```

now I want to update that model.

i used this same statement

```
$detailsAttribute->actions()->sync(Input::get('action_id'));
```

it creates the new actions but didn't remove the older ones. In other words, when I edit the model `$detailsAttribute`, I delete the older actions and I select **many new** ones.

my question is how to update the model considering removing the non selected actions?

Comment: Do you want the old `action_ids` to be removed? `sync()` is suppose to do so (i.e. it will remove everything that was in, and add the new `ids`)\

Answer (score 1):

`sync()` method will remove all those items from pivot table if they are not present in your
`Input::get('action_id') array`. If they are not removed that means you are also passing old  data in the new array. var_dump your Input and see what kind of array you are getting.